# Change pages of my navigation bar pressing a button

Tags: flutter, dart, material-ui, material-design

I have a `NavigationBar` with 3 tabs and i want to change the current tab or destination when i push on a button.

The Navigation Bar on the class Home:

```
body:IndexedStack(
        index: currentPageIndex,
        children: <Widget>[
          const ShopPage(),
          QRScanner(showTab2: () {
            setState(() {
              setState(() {
                currentPageIndex = 2;
              });
            });
          }),
          const ShopListPage(),
        ],
      ),    
bottomNavigationBar: NavigationBar(
            elevation: 2,
            labelBehavior: NavigationDestinationLabelBehavior.onlyShowSelected,
            selectedIndex: currentPageIndex,
            onDestinationSelected: (int index) {
              setState(() => currentPageIndex = index);
            },
            destinations: const [
              NavigationDestination(
                icon: Icon(Icons.store_outlined),
                selectedIcon: Icon(Icons.store),
                label: 'Tienda',
              ),
              NavigationDestination(
                icon: Icon(Icons.qr_code_scanner_outlined),
                selectedIcon: Icon(Icons.qr_code_scanner),
                label: 'Escaner',
              ),
              NavigationDestination(
                icon: Icon(Icons.shopping_cart_outlined),
                selectedIcon: Icon(Icons.shopping_cart),
                label: 'Carrito',
              ),
            ],
          ),
```

The function with the show dialog on the QRScanner page

```
void onQRViewCreated(QRViewController controller) {
setState(() {
  this.controller = controller;
});
controller.scannedDataStream.listen((scanData) {
  setState(() {
    result = scanData;
  });
  controller.pauseCamera();
  Stream<List<Products>> readProducts() => FirebaseFirestore.instance
      .collection('products')
      .where('id', isEqualTo: '${result!.code}')
      .snapshots()
      .map((snapshot) => snapshot.docs
          .map((doc) => Products.fromJson(doc.data()))
          .toList());

  Future<bool> onWillPop() async {
    return false;
  }

  showDialog(
    barrierDismissible: false,
    context: context,
    builder: (BuildContext context) => WillPopScope(
      onWillPop: () async => false,
      child: WillPopScope(
        onWillPop: onWillPop,
        child: Dialog(
          insetPadding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
          child: StreamBuilder<List<Products>>(
              stream: readProducts(),
              builder: (context, snapshot) {
                if (snapshot.hasError) {
                  return Text('Algo ha ocurrido! ${snapshot.error}');
                } else if (snapshot.hasData) {
                  final products = snapshot.data!;
                  return Container(
                    margin: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
                    child: Column(
                        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                        children: products
                            .map((p) => BuildQRCards( // This is the class which contain the button that should change tab on pressed
                                products: p, controller: controller,))
                            .toList()),
                  );
                } else {
                  return const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
                }
              }),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  );
});
}
```

The BuildQRCard Class:

```
  class _BuildQRCardsState extends State<BuildQRCards> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Card(
      clipBehavior: Clip.antiAlias,
      child: SizedBox(
        width: 300,
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          children: [
            Image(image: NetworkImage(widget.products.imageUrl)),
            ListTile(
              title: Text(widget.products.name),
              subtitle: Text('Precio: ${widget.products.price}\$'),
            ),
            Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
              children: [
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 0, 8, 8),
                  child: ElevatedButton(
                    style: ButtonStyle(
                      foregroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.all<Color>(
                        const Color(0xFFFFFFFF),
                      ),
                      backgroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.all<Color>(
                        const Color(0xFF6750A4),
                      ),
                    ),
                    onPressed: () {
                      Navigator.pop(context);
                      widget.controller!.resumeCamera();
                    },
                    child: const Text(
                      'Cancelar',
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 0, 8, 8),
                  child: ElevatedButton(
                    style: ButtonStyle(
                      foregroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.all<Color>(
                        const Color(0xFFFFFFFF),
                      ),
                      backgroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.all<Color>(
                        const Color(0xFF6750A4),
                      ),
                    ),
                    onPressed: () => showDialog(
                      context: context,
                      barrierDismissible: false,
                      builder: (BuildContext context) => AlertDialog(
                        content: Text(
                          '¿Desea añadir el producto ${widget.products.name} a la lista de compras?',
                          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                        ),
                        actions: <Widget>[
                          TextButton(
                              onPressed: () {
                                Navigator.pop(context);
                              },
                              child: const Text('Cancelar')),
                          TextButton(
                            onPressed: () {
                              passID(widget.products.id);
                              widget.controller!.resumeCamera();
                            },
                            child: const Text('Añadir'),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                    child: const Text(
                      'Añadir al Carro',
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

new answer

This has two approaches
Using a function and using result from navigator.pop

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(home: NavigationExample());
  }
}

class NavigationExample extends StatefulWidget {
  const NavigationExample({super.key});

  @override
  State<NavigationExample> createState() => _NavigationExampleState();
}

class _NavigationExampleState extends State<NavigationExample> {
  int currentPageIndex = 0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      bottomNavigationBar: NavigationBar(
        onDestinationSelected: (int index) {
          setState(() {
            currentPageIndex = index;
          });
        },
        selectedIndex: currentPageIndex,
        destinations: const <Widget>[
          NavigationDestination(
            icon: Icon(Icons.explore),
            label: 'Explore',
          ),
          NavigationDestination(
            icon: Icon(Icons.commute),
            label: 'Commute',
          ),
          NavigationDestination(
            selectedIcon: Icon(Icons.bookmark),
            icon: Icon(Icons.bookmark_border),
            label: 'Saved',
          ),
        ],
      ),
      body: <Widget>[
        MyPage1(
          showTab2: () {
            // how to use a function when they are in the same tab list
            setState(() {
              setState(() {
                currentPageIndex = 2;
              });
            });
          },
        ),
        Container(
          color: Colors.green,
          alignment: Alignment.center,
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              const Text('Page 2'),
              TextButton(
                  onPressed: () async {
                    // how to use the result
                    final int? result =
                        await Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(
                      builder: (context) {
                        return MyNewPage();
                      },
                    ));

                    if (result != null) {
                      setState(() {
                        currentPageIndex = result;
                      });
                    }
                  },
                  child: Text("new page"))
            ],
          ),
        ),
        Container(
          color: Colors.blue,
          alignment: Alignment.center,
          child: const Text('Page 3'),
        ),
      ][currentPageIndex],
    );
  }
}

class MyPage1 extends StatelessWidget {
  final Function showTab2;
  const MyPage1({Key? key, required this.showTab2}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      color: Colors.red,
      alignment: Alignment.center,
      child: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: [
          const Text('Page 1'),
          TextButton(
              onPressed: () {
                showTab2();
              },
              child: Text("Show tab 3"))
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyNewPage extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyNewPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
          child: Center(
        child: TextButton(
          onPressed: () => showDialog(
            context: context,
            barrierDismissible: false,
            builder: (BuildContext context) => AlertDialog(
              content: Text(
                '¿Desea añadir el producto ${'widget.products.name'} a la lista de compras?',
                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
              ),
              actions: <Widget>[
                TextButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                      Navigator.pop(context);
                      Navigator.pop(context);
                    },
                    child: const Text('Cancelar')),
                TextButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    // passID(widget.products.id);
                    // widget.controller!.resumeCamera();
                    Navigator.pop(context);
                    Navigator.pop(context, 0);
                  },
                  child: const Text('Añadir'),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          child: Text("Show dialog"),
        ),
      )),
    );
  }
}
```

/// END OF NEW ANSWER

//old answer
This line is what changes the tabs

```
 setState(() {
    setState(() => this.index = index);
  });
```

Hence if you want to change the tab through a different button just add something like this

```
 setState(() {
    setState(() => this.index = newTabIndex);
  });
```

where newTabIndex is the index of the tap you want to

in your case, you might have something like this

```
TextButton(
  onPressed: () {
    passID(products.id);
    Navigator.push(
      context,
      MaterialPageRoute(
        builder: (BuildContext context) =>
        BuildListCards(
          products: products)));
    controller!.resumeCamera();
    setState(() {
      setState(() => this.index = 1); // I am assuming 1 is the index of the tab you want to show
    });
  },
  child: const Text('Añadir')),
```

Comment: ok but the button is in another class so how can i pass the index between classes

Comment: If the button is in a different page, you can return a result from that other page and use it to set the tab

Comment: ok, i think i understand I'm gonna try it, sorry I'm newbie on coding

Comment: Sorry for the problem, can you show me an example? please and thanks

Comment: Okay, just a moment

Comment: Can you explain a bit how the app works? i'll probably be able to provide an adequate example if i know

You can see how to pass data back from  a new screen to an old screen you were on here 
https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/navigation/returning-data

Comment: My app scans a QR to show a dialog this dialog has the button that should send you to the page with index 2 and build a card on it, i update the code

Comment: are the qr page and the other page you want to show in the same tab?

Comment: no, one is qrpage and the other is shoplist

Comment: Okay, going through the changes you made

Comment: So the qr and shoplist are not part of the tabs list.
If they are not part of the tabs you can use result from Navigator.push and Navigator.pop to change the tab
But if they are part of the list of tabs, you can pass function to the qr page

Comment: Ok, so i have to learn how to use result and the navigators, thank you very much, you help me a lot, i think i guess search  in the documentation.

Comment: I've added some code which you can start with

Comment: Sorry bothering you again, I already understood what you said to me, but now I'm stuck because I realised that the button is in the tabs list specificly in the page QRScanner but in another class called BuildQRCard, i use this class to build the card in the show dialog so, i can't use a fuction because the button isn't in the QRScanner class and can't use the result because i dont use a navigator.push. I already updated the code.

Comment: The best way would have been using state management but for this.
You can use the function approach above.
See the MyPage1 class
You can pass the function all the way down to the widget that needs it.

Comment: Yes, I did that yesterday and its working fine. I had to use a `.them( )` on the `showdialog`. You helped me a lot, thank you so much